# NEM2 sdk for java not working on Glassfish server

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson-databind, nem

I have an Apache Tomcat (v9.0) development server, and I am using [nem2-sdk](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/definitely-use-the-or-a/) to perform blockchain operations. Everything works well on dev server, but when I deploy to production server which is a Glassfish (v4.1.2) server, blockchain functions give NoSuchFieldError for DeserializationFeature.USE_LONG_FOR_INTS which is already included in jackson-databind-2.9.3.jar file.

At first, I thought it was because I was using incompatible versions of jackson packages, like 2.9.0 for jackson-annotations, jackson-core and jackson-databind and 2.9.3 for for jackson-dataformat-yaml package. But I tried using 2.9.3 for all versions and still the error exists.

I also tried creating a new test project and implementing only one blockchain method, set up the server and everything, and it also has same issue. Works on apache tomcat dev server and not the glassfish server.

```
[2019-04-02T15:52:35.207+0800] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=26 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(2)] [timeMillis: 1554191555207] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[UserService]: Servlet.service() for servlet UserService threw exception
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: USE_LONG_FOR_INTS
    at io.nem.sdk.infrastructure.Http.<init>(Http.java:44)
    at io.nem.sdk.infrastructure.Http.<init>(Http.java:50)
    at io.nem.sdk.infrastructure.NetworkHttp.<init>(NetworkHttp.java:34)
    at io.nem.sdk.infrastructure.TransactionHttp.<init>(TransactionHttp.java:38)
    at my.com.app.nemHelper.NemHelper.<init>(NemHelper.java:45)
    at my.com.authenticate.User.createUserFrom(User.java:441)
    at my.com.authenticate.User.user(User.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ObjectOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:258)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at my.com.cmg.phis.mobile.authenticate.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally wound up commenting the line which caused the error from the nem2-sdk source code and used my version.

I am not sure of the root cause of the issue, but I think it is because of conflicting versions of jackson-databind in the Glassfish production server which causes my version of jackson-databind to be not read. And as of now, the server I am using is not dedicated to my project, so I cannot change the version of jackson-databind included in the server.

Note:- This is not a solution to the problem, just a workaround. It worked for my requirements, but not sure if it will work in a general case.

If anyone finds a better answer, please update here. Thanks